# how to set image on a selected point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a scale which indicate the difference of two date .I am able to calculate the difference of date (current date and expected date ). But I need to add image on the scale I ned to add this image on this scale

http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/256/Map-Marker-Bubble-Azure-icon.png

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/o88h3d4h/

is there any other way to show difference of two date on a scale ? any chart ?

```
var expectedDate="06/10/2015";

var todayDay="06/03/2015"

function setImageOfDifferenceOFDate(todayDay,expectedDate){
  var date1 = new Date(todayDay);
var date2 = new Date(expectedDate);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);  

}

$(document).ready(function(){

setImageOfDifferenceOFDate(todayDay,expectedDate)    
})
```

Comment: If you don't have any browser requirements, you can take a look at the html5 canvas which would let you draw whatever you want. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

First your IDs must start with a letter, change every ID to some thing like `d1`, `d2`..

Second the CSS property for bg image is `background-image`, also if you want to use a base64 image, you need to put it inside a `url( )` property.
The Image needs witdh/height and should positioned `absolute` so you can use `position: left/right`.

I took the half `width` (in my example 50px / 2 = 25px) and decreased it with the half of one `span` Element. So you using `%` values, I just used Chrome Dev Console to look which real width it has, something like `10.7px` / 2 = `5.3px`

Now like said: `25px - 5.3px = 19.7px`. If we negate this the image mid should point to the calculated diffDay (Today is Friday, 3. July. 2015, the script alerts 7 so it took `id="d7"`).

Inside the Javascript part, it just create a `span` Element, adds your classname and appends on the current `id="d7"` Element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o88h3d4h/6/

Comment: I didn't changed every `id=`, just the first 20 or so.. you have to change every of then :-) So add a `d` in front of the ids.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use any of the following.

1. [jQueryUI Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin)
2. [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/demo.html)

[Here](http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2010/02/21/using-a-jquery-ui-slider-to-select-a-time-range/) is another tutorial explaining **jQueryUI Slider**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `setImageOfDifferenceOFDate` function

```
var myImage = new Image(50, 50);
myImage.src = '//icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/256/Map-Marker-Bubble-Azure-icon.png';
$("#"+diffDays).html(myImage);
```

See this JSFiddle link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/o88h3d4h/9/